# Mediapipe making python local server throw "[WinError 6] The handle is invalid"

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, mediapipe

For a certain application, I want to have 1 main script run 2 scripts: one that uses mediapipe and another one that opens an HTML file through a Python local server. However, when linking the file importing mediapipe, it for whatever reason throws the error: "[WinError 6] The handle is invalid"

Code running in Python 3.9 Anaconda environment with Mediapipe version: mediapipe==0.10.11 (Mediapipe is causing trouble in later Python versions)

```
> Opening browser...
Starting httpd server on port 8000
Failed to start server: [WinError 6] Controlador no válido
```

If the mediapipe import is commented, it works perfectly as intended.

Project structure:

```
./main.py
./server/make_a_server.py
./mp/gesture_detection.py
./server/anhtml.html
```

main.py

```py
from server.make_a_server import open_browser
from mp.gesture_detection import detect

def main():
    open_browser(8000)
    detect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

make_a_server.py

```py
import os
import threading
import keyboard
import webbrowser
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

def get_full_path(relative_path):
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(current_dir, relative_path)

def start_server(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, port=8000):
    try:
        server_address = ('', port)
        httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
        print(f"Starting httpd server on port {port}")
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to start server: {e}")

def open_browser(port):
    print("> Opening browser...")
    relative_path = 'anhtml.html'
    full_path = get_full_path(relative_path)
    directory = os.path.dirname(full_path)

    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server, args=(HTTPServer, lambda *args, directory='.', **kwargs: SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(*args, directory=directory, **kwargs), port,))
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()

    url = f"http://localhost:{port}/{os.path.basename(relative_path)}"
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

    keyboard.wait('q')
```

gesture_detection.py

```py
import mediapipe as mp

def detect():
    pass
```

Project idea is to send gesture data from mediapipe to the website and move a folium map, but for the sake of getting to the root cause, I stripped as much irrelevant code while keeping the same error behavior. Both folders have **init**.py to properly link between folders.

Any idea what could be happening? Is this an issue from my side?

Made sure that I was using the latest Mediapipe version, uninstalling it and reinstalling. Creating a new environment and only installing Mediapipe.

I even tried making the Python local server not start through threading, just in case that was an issue. Didn't work either.

Comment: Didn't solve the core issue, but a work around I found was manually starting the python localhost server (`python -m http.server 8000`) and then executing the mediapipe script in another terminal.